# Passing data between veiws.py and template.html in django

Tags: python, django

I am new in Django. I want to write a very simple code to create a string in views.py and shows in an html file in templates.:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse

def index(request):
    F = 100
    response = str(F + 10)
    response1 = {"Main": response}
    template_name = "homepage.html"
    return render(request, template_name, response1)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='homepage.html'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)]
```

homepage.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <h1>User Information</h1>
</head>
<h2>Answer: {{response1}}</h2>

</html>
```

What I get on webpage is the headers without {{response1}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
  <h1>User Information</h1>
</head>
<h2>Answer: {{Main}}</h2>

</html>
```

Use this

Comment: Thanks. that works, but why? if I had to pass two variables, what do I have to do then? DO I have to use dict to pass each var?

Comment: Well the main key that you defined in your dictionary was Main not response1